# Bootstrap Flatty and jQueryUI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to implement a normal jQueryUI datepicker on a CSS template that can be found at http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0P6NR1N. This template has built in date/time pickers (To be found under Forms > Form Components), but I cannot get them to work. The documentation is very lacking as to what to include to get this working. Also, I do not want to use the popup "button" at the side of the text box, but rather have it pop up when the user focuses on the text box.

I have tried the normal jQueryUI datepicker code as follows, but even though I get no error calling the `datepicker()` function, no date picker is popping up.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control hasDatepicker" id="date_of_birth" name="date_of_birth" type="text" placeholder="DATE OF BIRTH" data-format="YYYY-MM-DD" data-validation="length" data-validation-error-msg="Please enter valid date of birth" data-validation-length="min10,max10">
</div>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.hasDatepicker').datepicker();
});
```

I am looking for any advice on getting either the bootstrap flatty datepicker or the normal jQueryUI datepicker working.

I have created a JsFiddle resource with all the external resources loaded at http://jsfiddle.net/7A8CM/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this part

```
<input class="form-control hasDatepicker"
```

Is wrong because hasDatepicker is actually a class for jquery UI so if we remove that and change it to this:

```
<input class="form-control"
```

and then change the javascript to:

```
$('.form-control').datepicker();
```

It will work!

Check it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/JY8uj/